# "wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32" loading shared object file

Tags: python

I have a simple Python program that is trying to call a shared object file on a 32-bit system, and I've also tested this on a 64-bit system and I presume the .SO file is 32-bit (as it's an SDK based file that was given to me for an embedded system). Although when I run my program I'm getting an import error.

**My code:**

```
import libCVAPIV01_DESFire

CV_SetCommunicationType(1)

ActiveBuzzer(0,1,[])
```

**The error:**

```
ImportError: /home/paul/Downloads/Test/libCVAPIV01_DESFire.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I literally have been stuck with this all day and cannot figure out why. I've read online it must be the device BIT (32/64) that causing the problem but I've tried this on a 32 bit machine and on my Raspberry Pi that is 32 bit--ideally I want this to run on the Pi but it just doesn't work.

My `libCVAPIV01_DESFire.py` file:

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'libCVAPIV01_DESFire.so')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

Running Python 2.7.

Any ideas?

Comment: Raspberry Pi is 32bit, but not x86. Please post the output of `file /home/paul/Downloads/Test/libCVAPIV01_DESFire.so`.

Comment: @Kay updated with my loading file, any ideas?

Comment: @PaulNess, ...the request was for the output of using the `file` command. Your edit is not responsive to that request.

Comment: ...and as Kay says, not all 32-bit architectures are compatible with each other.

Comment: ...the Pi is 32-bit, yes, but ARM. Something built for ia32/x86 will never work there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understand that. I'm testing it on my x86 machine as well, I also have an ARM .so file and I've tested it on my machine and the Pi, but it's not working on either architecture.

Comment: Have you given us the output of `file /home/paul/Downloads/Test/libCVAPIV01_DESFire.so` yet?

Comment: I presume you're expecting this: libCVAPIV01_DESFire.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=b980255c00b51d3366d5a72fd6c561de5014f5ef, not stripped - if not, I can Dropbox it (apologies, my knowledge is limited in this stuff and I'm trying my best to figure it out!).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was expecting. So -- x86, not ARM, so if this is going to work anywhere, it'll be on your PC.

Comment: ...so, next thing: On that PC, with a 32-bit Python interpreter (which should be fine even if the larger OS is x86_64, assuming a multilib distro), can you `dlopen()` it with the Python ctypes module?